# Read from blocking IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I receive blocking IEnumerable (like never ending stream) from library function. Sometimes it contains a few messages, and sometimes a lot of. I need to fetch all existing messages from it, and I don't want to wait for new messages.

This code fetches existing messages and waits until 10 s timeout.

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
foreach (var data in consumer.Consume(cancellationTokenSource.Token))
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.message);
}
```

How should I modify my code?

```
public IEnumerable<Message> Consume(CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267317(v=vs.110).aspx BlockingCollection<T>.ToArray may work but not sure so only a comment

Comment: What is the type of the `consumer` variable?

Comment: Alas, ToArray() waits for end in this never ending streem.

Comment: "consumer" is subject specific object

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186(v=vs.110).aspx sounds like what you really want the enumerable to be. Are you in control of the library producing the enumerable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

workaround

So, we have infinite IEnumerable. If there are no messages in it, "foreach" will wait for their appearance. Fortunately, our "Consume" method accepts a cancellation token, and we can change it within loop. After processing of first message from IEnumerable, I set "CancelAfter(1000)" - something like timeout. If new message comes in a second, the timer resets. When the queue is empty, the timer fires, and we break the loop (try... catch for OperationCanceledException needed)

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(1000);
foreach (var data in consumer.Consume(cancellationTokenSource.Token))
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.message);
    cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(1000);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain *how/why* your workaround works? That'll enable the OP and others to understand and apply your workaround (where applicable) elsewhere. — [During review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10301388)

Answer (score 0):

I would abstract the problem out further. I personally wouldn't perform consumption while looping the data. I would implement a threading timer that enqueued to a Stack or Queue. Then have your loop Pop items for processing. You may even find that you want to use a ConcurrentQueue in order to deal with volatility.

Answer (score 0):

I think [BlockingCollection.TryTake](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287184(v=vs.110).aspx) will do what you are looking for

> If the collection is empty, this method immediately returns false.

```
while (bc.TryTake(out T))
{
}
```